# html form send blank

Tags: html

I have a html form on my website, but people keep forgetting to fill it in completely (3 boxes to fill in).

Is their a way with html to only activate the submit button if they have filled it in completely or something similar?

Comment: why are not using simple javascript validations to keep the form unsubmit untill your specified values are given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a javascript function to check fields and then call that function on the onsubmit event of your form.

```
function validate()
{
 if(document.formname.txtbox1.value=='')
 {
   alert("enter value");
   document.formname.txtbox1.focus();
   return false;        
        }
```

and then call it onsubmit event of your form

```
<form name = "formname" action = "abc.php" method ="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript validation is the route most go down here. If you're already using the jQuery library, I would recommend http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two steps to "make sure" that they've filled in the required fields.  The first step is [client-side validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), which offers the user a helpful UI to direct them to fill out the form properly.  The second step is server-side validation, which returns an error to the user and re-displays the form if they tried to post it incorrectly.  (We don't have enough information to be particularly helpful with the second part, it depends on your server-side environment.)